# How to add a linear constraint in CPLEX Python API?

Tags: python, constraints, cplex

Linear program:

```
Decision Variables:
x[]

Maximize:  Sum(i to n) (fare[i] * x[i])

subject to:
x[i] <= demand[i]
```

I am trying to add a linear constraint in cplex using Python, but I am not able to get the syntax correct.

```
fare = [400.0, 700.0, 600.0]
dmd= [2, 4, 3]
itins = []
for count in range(3):
        i = Itinerary(count, 1, dmd[count], fare[count])
        itins.append(i)


# problem variables
X=[] * len(itins)

def setupproblem(c):

    c.objective.set_sense(c.objective.sense.maximize)
    num_x = range(len(itins))
    print (num_x)

    varnames = ["X"+str(j) for j in range(len(itins))]
    c.variables.add(names = varnames, lb=[0.0, 0, 0], ub=[10.0, 10, 10])
    x = [c.variables.add(obj=fare)  for i in num_x]

 i_iten = range(len(itins))

    c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr  = [cplex.SparsePair(ind = i_iten,
                                                     val = X[i])
                                          for i in range(len(itins) -1 )],
                             senses = ["L"],
                             rhs   = capacity,
                             names = ["capacity_"+str(i)
                                      for i in i_iten])
```

I am getting this error:

```
raise CplexError(" %d: Invalid name -- '%s'\n" % tuple(self._mat))
cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexError:  1210: Invalid name -- 'X'
```

Comment: Can you write a linear program that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @serge_k : Added the linear problem. It trying to maximize the revenue (fare * number) subject to constraints.

Comment: You have strange bounds type when adding variables: the first elements in `lb` and `ub` are `float` and the others are `int`. Are `x[1]` and `x[2]` assumed to be integer types? In that case you need to specify types as by default variables are initialized as continuous.

Comment: Thanks serge_k, its just to get it working. Im trying to get my hands on the python APIs. But yes, they are assumed to be integer types.

Answer (score 2):

In `cplex.SparcePair` you need to specify nonzero elements under `val` and the corresponding variables under `ind`. Plus, from your linear program your right-hand side should be `dmd`.

```
c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr  = [cplex.SparsePair(ind = xname,
                                                 val = [1.0])
                                      for xname in varnames],
                         senses = ["L"],
                         rhs   = dmd,
                         names = ["capacity_"+str(i)
                                  for i in i_iten])
```

Also I would suggest to indicate the objective function when you add variables:

```
c.variables.add(obj = fare, names = varnames, lb=[0.0, 0, 0], ub=[10.0, 10, 10])
```

Comment: Tried this, but it says _raise CplexError("Inconsistent arguments")_

Comment: I got it working. very slight modification.  

 `c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[xname],  val=[1.0]) for xname in varn], senses=["L"] * len(varnames), rhs=dmd)`  

But facing a weird problem.  
The line of code to add a new linear constraint works fine in the python interactive. But when i run the code through a file it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[xname], val=[1.0]) for xname in varn], senses=["L"] * len(varnames), rhs=dmd)`

But before you add the constraints on the variables, please keep in mind that the variable names should be added to the function. I spent 4 hours going round and round to figure out what was going wrong.

This line should come first.
`c.variables.add(varnames)`

Thanks serge_k for your initial pointers !!